# Как правильно перевести динамический контент в Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

Доброго времени суток!

Использую этот метод для хранения и извлечения переводов в БД вместо message.properties
https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7

Проблема следующая: есть функционал создания страниц из админки, где можно указать переводы для контента и для мета данных. Как быть в том случае, если страницы создаются динамически и соответственно, для каждого из них будет один и тот же key?

```
<meta name="description" th:content="${metaData.pageMetaDescription}">
<meta name="keywords" th:content="${metaData.pageMetaKeywords}">
<title th:text="${metaData.pageMetaTitle}">Custom Title</title>
```

Получается, что и для страницы контактов и для главной страницы будет неуникальный ключ pageMetaTitle. И при извлечении из БД будет конфликт.

Для "статичных" страниц проблем нет, так как прописаны свои уник. ключи...

Comment: как вариант - добавьте в таблицу переводов поле page_id, тогда сможете отбирать metaData для конкретной страницы

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Я думал над тем, чтобы добавить в таблицу 4-й параметр (колонку) и по нему уже ориентироваться... Думал, может быть есть другие решения)